# Are the terms "click url" and "click through url" interchangeable?

Tags: web-services, ads, advertisement-server

Simple question... What's the answer?

I've been reading up on creating an ad serving service and I see different usages of these two terms. Some make it seem that the two terms are the same, some make me think that they are somehow distinct.

Answer (score 1):

"Click Url" Gives me the impression that when I click the URL i will be shown my destination (page).

Where-as "Cick Through Url" gives me the impression I will click the link, and an advert or some form of marketing (of sorts) will appear and then AFTER that I will be shown my destination(page).

Comment: Well they both are supposed to take you to the ad's destination once clicked. However, one of the distinctions that I've read claims that click-through somehow implies that the user actually reaches the destination... But since the developer has no way to ensure this happens, not sure why we would be referring to the urls differently from a programming perspective.

Comment: I would have thought that one displays an advert inline and the other pops an advert out into a separate window, thus the developer ensures that either way the user will get to the destination. Yet the former (click url) gives the impression your going direct to the destination, where-as the other implies your going via (as in through) another page